# Sorting using Map-Reduce - Possible approach

Tags: python, sorting, hadoop, bigdata, hadoop-streaming

I have a large dataset with 500 million rows and 58 variables. I need to sort the dataset using one of the 59th variable which is calculated using the other 58 variables. The variable happens to be a floating point number with four places after decimal.

There are two possible approaches:

1. The normal merge sort
2. While calculating the 59th variables, i start sending variables in particular ranges to to particular nodes. Sort the ranges in those nodes and then combine them in the reducer once i have perfectly sorted data and now I also know where to merge what set of data; It basically becomes appending.

Which is a better approach and why?

Comment: Is it hard to try both? you can get a good idea to see which one is faster. Although, it seems to me that merge sort would be much faster if you have enough memory because you wouldn't need to partially sort sub-problems which would force you to access the hard-disk several times which is the bottleneck in speed

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that you are looking for a total sort order without a secondary sort for all your rows. I should also mention that 'better' is never a good question since there is typically a trade-off between time and space and in Hadoop we tend to think in terms of space rather than time unless you use products that are optimized for time (TeraData has the capability of putting Databases in memory for Hadoop use)

Out of the two possible approaches you mention, I think only one would work within the Hadoop infrastructure. Num 2, Since Hadoop leverages many nodes to do *one* job, sorting becomes a little trickier to implement and we typically want the 'shuffle and sort' phase of MR to take care of the sorting since distributed sorting is at the heart of the programming model.

At the point when the 59th variable is generated, you would want to sample the distribution of that variable so that you can send it through the framework then merge like you mentioned. Consider the case when the variable distribution of x contain 80% of your values. What this might do is send 80% of your data to one reducer who would do most of the work. This assumes of course that some keys will be grouped in the sort and shuffle phase which would be the case unless you programmed them unique. It's up to the programmer to set up partitioners to evenly distribute the load by sampling the key distribution.

If on the other hand we were to sort in memory then we could accomplish the same thing during reduce but there are inherent scalability issues since the sort is only as good as the amount of memory available in the node currently running the sort and dies off quickly when it starts to use HDFS to look for the rest of the data that did not fit into memory. And if you ignored the sampling issue you will likely run out of memory unless all your key values pairs are evenly distributed and you understand the memory capacity within your data.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Hadoop Comparator Class Part of [HadoopStreaming Wiki Page](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/streaming.html)

You can move the datasets to HDFS, use Python to write a mapper and do a hadoop streaming mapper only job. The Hadoop Streaming will automatically help you sort them.

Then you can use hdfs dfs -getmerge and -copyToLocal to move the sorted records back to local if you want.